# How can I pop() the last element of 2 arrays in single call using className?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two DIV-elements, which are assigned an array called "stack" using `data()`.

Both DIV-elements have a class of `.trigger`.

I now want to `pop()` the last element of both arrays like so:

```
$('.trigger').data("stack").pop()
```

However this only takes off the last element of the FIRST array, although

```
$('trigger').length
```

Returns `2`.

Is there a way to remove the last element from both arrays in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$('.trigger').each(function() { $(this).data('stack').pop(); });
```

In general, jQuery functions that return a value (like ".data()" or ".css()" when passed just 1 string argument) only operate on the first element in the matched array.  Thus when you want to do something like your deal, you use an explicit ".each()" to get at each element yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use 'map' -

```
var arr = $('.trigger').map(function() {
    return $(this).data("stack").pop()
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/5gvAH/

As Pointy points out this solution works well if you need the values that were popped from each array. If you just want to pop off the values and don't need the returned values then Pointy's suggestion would be the best fit.

Comment: Yes, this is correct if it's desirable to gather up the values popped off the arrays.

Comment: Good to know. For now I just need to remove the elements without retrieving the values. Still Thanks.

Comment: My first response on seeing this is 'Holy cow! That's cool!'  Thanks for this.  I love stumbling across cool code snippets even when I'm not really looking.